# Extract items under set value from ArrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist, return

I have an array list set up cars = new ArrayList(); which works fine but I need to cycle through the list of cars in the list and pick out any one under 10000, i have the variable budget set at 10000. I also need to return the RegNumber which is a field in the car in the array list. below is what I have and it just wont work for me. Any ideas?

```
public String listBudgetCars()
{
    if (cars.size() > 0)
    {   
        for (Car car : cars)
        {
            if(car.getPrice() > budget)
            {
                listBudgetCars = car;
            }
        }
        return listBudgetCars.getRegNumber();
    }
    else
    {
       return "No Cars";
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem? Also, show us code that compiles, please.

Comment: You don't have the variable `listBudgetCars` declared. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly "doesn't work"? It won't compile as is unless `listBudgetCars` is defined somewhere.

Comment: What return value do you expect? It's a String. The list seems to contain Car objects. And the method name starts with 'list' which suggests that its returning something list-like...

Comment: The return value I expect is a String along the lines of "132 w 123". it is a regNumber string in the car element. The listBudgetCars is initialised as a string but it says its an incompatible type with car.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `cars` is initialized and populated elsewhere, you want something like this:

```
public List<Car> budgetCars() {
    List<Car> budgetCars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.price < budget) {
            budgetsCars.add(car);
        }
    }

    return budgetCars;
}
```

And now `budgetsCars` is a list of the cars you need.

Comment: Or use Google Guava filter http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection, com.google.common.base.Predicate)

Comment: Indeed so, but I think it is easiest for a beginner to understand the facilities of the core language first before contemplating third-party libraries. Heck, different JVM languages altogether like Scala and Clojure would make this super easy too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 8, you can apply the filter function :

```
List<Cars> budgetCars = cars.stream()
                            .filter(c -> c.getPrice() < budget)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick any one car under the budget and return the registration number. Assuming the first occurrence pick.

BigDecimal is recommended for currency though. [used int]

```
public static String getRegistrationNumberUnderBudget(List<Car> cars, int budget) {
   if(cars != null) {
       for(Car car : cars) {
           if(car.getPrice() < budget) {
               return car.getRegNumber();
           }
       }
   } 
   return "No cars found";
}
```